# How to reset environment after running vcvars32.bat

Tags: visual-c++, command-line, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file to run some builds using Visual C++. I would like to "undo" the vsvars32.bat/vcvarsXX.bat changes at the end of the script so that I leave the environment unchanged from before the script ran.

Example 1 - using vsvars32.bat

```
call %VS100COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat
devenv myProject.sln /Build "Debug|Win32"
:: Now undo vsvars32.bat
```

Example 2 - using vcvars32.bat and vcvars64.bat

```
<path to VC bin>vcvars32.bat
:: cmd line build calls for 32 bit application
:: Now undo vcvars32.bat

<path to VC bin>amd64\vcvars64.bat
:: cmd line build calls for 64 bit application
:: Now undo vcvars64.bat
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is simple - SETLOCAL coupled with ENDLOCAL. Type `HELP SETLOCAL` or `HELP ENDLOCAL` to get more info on usage.

Example 1:

```
setlocal
call %VS100COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat
devenv myProject.sln /Build "Debug|Win32"
endlocal
```

Example 2:

```
setlocal
<path to VC bin>vcvars32.bat
:: cmd line build calls for 32 bit application
endlocal

setlocal    
<path to VC bin>amd64\vcvars64.bat
:: cmd line build calls for 64 bit application
endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler if your build.bat will be called by:

```
cmd.exe /c build.bat
```

This will:

1. Create child process with copy of current environment.
2. Modify this environment.
3. Run build in modified child environment.
4. discard child environment on process exit.

So nothing will change in current environment, and cleanup will be not necessary.